# is it possible to fetch database DDL in teradata

Tags: teradata

i know we can use SHOW TABLE DATABASENAME.TABLENAME to get the DDL of a certain table in teradata,

like,

```
show table customerservice.employee;
```

result:

```
CREATE SET TABLE customerservice.employee ,FALLBACK ,
 NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
 NO AFTER JOURNAL,
 CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
 DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
 (
  employee_number INTEGER,
  manager_employee_number INTEGER,
  department_number INTEGER,
  job_code INTEGER,
  last_name CHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
  hire_date DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD' NOT NULL,
  birthdate DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD' NOT NULL,
  salary_amount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL)
  UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( employee_number );
```

If i want to show DDL of a certain database, is it possible ?

Comment: Not with a single request. You can create all SHOW commands based on `dbc.TablesV`, using a CASE over `TableKind` to get `SHOW TABLE/VIEW/MACRO/etc.`

Comment: @dnoeth thanks,i found i can get DDL of a database from teradata studio